# Why does `text-scale-increase` not affect `window-text-width`

Tags: window, scaling

I am trying to calculate how many characters are being displayed in a window, but the information I get from `(window-text-width)` isn't updated if I call `(text-scale-increase)`. Why?

A typical session might be

```
(window-text-width) ; => 90
(text-scale-increase 1) ; => t
(window-text-width) ; => 90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Frame Font`

> Each frame has a “default font” which specifies the default character
>   size for that frame.  This size is meant when retrieving or changing the
>   size of a frame in terms of columns or lines (see Size Parameters).
>   It is also used when resizing (see Window Sizes) or splitting (see
>   Splitting Windows) windows.

Note that this value is *frame* specific, not *buffer* specific, so
the buffer-local remapping of the `default` face performed by
`text-scale-increase` does not have any effect on this.

Note also that a buffer may have a range of disparate character widths
on display, in which case, even if the default character size was on a
per buffer basis, a single value would still not (necessarily) be
applicable to all characters.

Answer (score 1):

It does not do what you expect (and request) because the Emacs maintainers rejected that possibility.  I even provided [a patch](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2009-08/msg00414.html) to realize it, as soon as text-scaling was made available.

See [this message](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=8379#16) in bug thread #8379.

Fortunately, you can get what you want by using library [`face-remap+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/face-remap%2b.el).  It gives you user option **`text-scale-resize-window`**:

> **`text-scale-resize-window`** is a variable defined in [`face-remap+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/face-remap%2b.el).
>
> Its value is t
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means text scaling resizes the window or frame accordingly.
>   For example, if you use `C-x C--` (`text-scale-decrease`) to make the
>   text smaller, then the window or frame is made smaller by a similar
>   factor.
>
> If the window is not alone in its frame, then the window is resized.
>   Otherwise, the frame is resized (provided you also use library
>   [`fit-frame.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/fit-frame.el)).  The frame is always resized both horizontally and
>   vertically.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you for the libraries, they will be very useful! You solved my problem. (I marked @phils answer as correct though because of the way the question was posed.)